Setting map extents in print composer using a polygon layer?
I have a group of data points that need to be encapsulated within different polygons. I have used the geometries by expression tool to generate a layer of these polygons. I'm trying to feed the polygon layer in to the atlas so that the map extents match the size and position of the polygons.

So... you set the atlas to the polygon extents and your question is?
